# REST endpoints limited in v1

Tags: api, rest-api

I have been in the process of building a [simple frontend](https://github.com/webjay/mageArt) for Magento, but stopped because the API only allow access to products, categories, orders and customers, and I would at least also need Brands.
Is there a plugin or other way I can get the information I need via a REST endpoint?
If I upgrade to Magento 2, would that help?

Comment: The REST API is fairly easy to extend, so it's probably worth you looking into how to do that. For example, I recently had to add an API for retrieving static CMS blocks - it's some XML, a couple of empty reference classes and a single method defining the "controller like" retrieval logic

Answer (score -1):

You can customize a native API REST of Magento with third-party module:
https://medium.com/@denniswalters84/how-to-extend-and-customize-magento-rest-api-a842d0071682

When you upgrade to Magento 2, you should rewrite your module.